# cs193p assignment 4 flickr fetcher returns an empty array

Tags: ios, flickr, cs193p

I am following the iTunesU lecture of stanford cs193p class, and I am on assignment 4 right now. After I entered the API key in the header file and try to log the returned array to the console, it shows that it is an empty array with nothing in it. Is the code provided not working anymore since there has been changes to the flickr API?

The FlickrFetcher class code can be accessed here: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/assignments/FlickrFetcher.zip

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it with my Flickr key and it works.  I called it like so:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [FlickrFetcher topPlaces]);
```

By the way, you are doing the Fall 2011 version of the course which is iOS 5
based.  There is a new Winter 2013 version of the course which is iOS 6 based
which can be found here:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/coding-together-developing/id593208016

Comment: It worked for me the first time.  Then I tried it with incorrect Flickr keys to see what the behavior was.  The result was (null).  Then I tried the correct key again, and I'm getting the same result that you are - empty array.  I have the app running on my iPad from when I did assignment 4, and it returns nothing for topPlaces, so the API seems flaky.

Comment: And, its working again.  This seems to be a problem at Flickr.  My iPad app for assignment 4 works and I've done nothing to it in 1.5 years.

Comment: yeah it seems it's working now. I was thinking of doing the iOS 5 version first and then do the iOS 6 again. Do you think that's worth it?

Comment: Actually, I did the entire iOS 5 version and was really impressed with the entire course.  The latest course is almost as good, but there are a few rough spots.  If you have the time to do both versions, I do think it is worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks! that's what I thought when I browsed the contents covered in these 2 versions as well. I thought the iOS 5 version was a little bit more complete.

Answer (score 2):

As of June 27, 2014, all the http's are required by flickr to be changed to https